# Is there a reason for why it doesn't enter some of the else-if statements?

Tags: c, if-statement, c-strings, strcmp

Some of the else-if statements aren't working like the 'else if(strcmp(player1,player2) == 0)
' or the 'else if(strcmp(player1, "scissors") == 0)'. Could it be their subsequent 'if' statements? They are replicas (with some modification) from the other else if statements that do work. They are nearly identical so I don't get why they wouldn't work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    
    char player1[25];
    char player2[25];
    
    while(1){
        
        printf("please type one of the following: rock, paper or scissors. Player1 goes first\n");
        scanf("%24s%24s",player1,player2);
        
        if (strcmp(player1, "rock") == 0)
        {
            if (strcmp(player2, "scissors") == 0)
                printf("player 1 wins, rock crushes scissors\n");
        }
        
        else if(strcmp(player1, "rock") == 0)
        {
            if (strcmp(player2, "paper") == 0)
                printf("player 2 wins, paper covers rock\n");
        }

        
        
        else if(strcmp(player1, "scissors") == 0)
        {
            if(strcmp(player2, "paper") == 0)
                printf("player 1 wins, scissor cuts paper\n");
        }
        
        else if(strcmp(player1, "scissors") == 0)
        {
            if(strcmp(player2, "rock") == 0)
                printf("player 2 wins, rock crushes scissors\n");
        }

        
        else if(strcmp(player1, "paper") == 0)
        {
            if(strcmp(player2, "rock") == 0)
                printf("player 1 wins, paper covers rock\n");
        }
        
        else if(strcmp(player1, "paper") == 0)
        {
            if(strcmp(player2, "scissors") == 0)
                printf("player 2 wins, scissor cuts paper\n");
        }

        
        

        else if(strcmp(player2, "rock") == 0)
        {
            if (strcmp(player1, "scissors") == 0)
                printf("player 2 wins, rock crushes scissors\n");
        }
        
        else if(strcmp(player2, "rock") == 0)
        {
            if (strcmp(player1, "paper") == 0)
                printf("player 1 wins, paper covers rock\n");
        }

        
        else if(strcmp(player2, "scissors") == 0)
        {
            if(strcmp(player1, "paper") == 0)
                printf("player 2 wins, scissor cuts paper\n");
        }
        
        else if(strcmp(player2, "scissors") == 0)
        {
            if(strcmp(player1, "rock") == 0)
                printf("player 1 wins, rock crushes scissors\n");
        }

        
        else if(strcmp(player2, "paper") == 0)
        {
            if(strcmp(player1, "rock") == 0)
                printf("player 2 wins, paper covers rock\n");
        }
        
        else if(strcmp(player2, "paper") == 0)
        {
            if(strcmp(player1, "scissors") == 0)
                printf("player 1 wins, scissor cuts paper\n");
        }

        
        else if(strcmp(player1,player2) == 0)
        {
            printf("nobody wins, let’s sing it again!\n");
        }
        else
            printf("incorrect input, try again\n");
    }

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: What are the inputted strings?

Comment: when you have "if (condition) {} else if (exactly same condition) {}", what do you expect the latter to do?

Comment: Jonathan, Carefully review the `if ... else...` structure.

Comment: rock rock        and  scissors rock

Comment: "nearly identical" won't "work the same".

Comment: "aren't working" is not a very specific description of the problem. Please specify the exact input required to reproduce the problem, as well as the intended and actual behavior of your program.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your if-else statements do not make a sense. For example consider these if-else statements

```
    else if(strcmp(player1, "scissors") == 0)
    {
        if(strcmp(player2, "paper") == 0)
            printf("player 1 wins, scissor cuts paper\n");
    }
    
    else if(strcmp(player1, "scissors") == 0)
    {
        if(strcmp(player2, "rock") == 0)
            printf("player 2 wins, rock crushes scissors\n");
    }
```

The both else if statements have the same condition

```
    else if(strcmp(player1, "scissors") == 0)
    //...
    else if(strcmp(player1, "scissors") == 0)
```

So the second else if statement either will not be executed or its condition will never be equal to true.

For example you could write a separate if statements the following way

```
    if (strcmp(player1, "rock") == 0)
    {
        if (strcmp(player2, "scissors") == 0)
            printf("player 1 wins, rock crushes scissors\n");
        else if (strcmp(player2, "paper") == 0)
            printf("player 2 wins, paper covers rock\n");
    }
    else if(strcmp(player1, "scissors") == 0)
    {
        if(strcmp(player2, "paper") == 0)
            printf("player 1 wins, scissor cuts paper\n");
        else if(strcmp(player2, "rock") == 0)
            printf("player 2 wins, rock crushes scissors\n");
    }
    //...
```